# LNK1103 when linking ODBCCP32.lib using Visual C++ 2017 targetting XP (v141_xp) in debug mode

Tags: c++, mfc, linker, odbc, visual-studio-2017

When attempting to upgrade a program that was originally built in Visual Studio 2010 to target 2017, I am getting LNK1103 errors when linking odbccp32.lib indicating:

`debugging information corrupt; recompile module`

I have included legacy_stdio_definitions.lib, which seems to be required to resolve symbol issues with legacy static libraries, but I still get the error about debug information.

Release builds work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this is actually a compiler problem with certain versions of Visual Studio 2017.  Versions 15.3 and 15.4 have this problem, and short of linking in non-debug mode, I was unable to find a good solution in these compiler versions.

I did, however, find a [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/99785/mfcs140libstdafxobj-fatal-error-lnk1103-debugging.html) thread detailing this issue, which apparently affects a number of legacy libraries when linking using Visual Studio 2017 versions 15.3.x and 15.4.x.

According to MSFT staff in that thread, the problem is resolved in 15.5.  From the thread linked above:

> YongKang Zhu [MSFT] · Oct 04 at 11:08 AM
>   Thanks for the report. The problem has been fixed in VS 2017 Update 5.

I was able to confirm this is the case by installing the current 15.5 preview version and successfully linking the library.

I added this question and answer because existing search information on this topic seems extremely poor.

Comment: This is not a sufficient error analysis. What is the issue? What have you done to diagnose it? What results did you get? Is there an official statement?

Comment: Fair enough.  Answer updated with the details I have.  As this was an internal linker error, little of the flailing around I did trying to get past it (other than linking in non-debug mode, which works and which I mentioned) is relevant.

Comment: That's better. Still unfortunate, that there are no details communicated by MSFT about the bug itself, what causes it to surface, and which libraries of build configurations are affected.